# How to pass value of property of object to function

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner with JavaScript and I was trying to solve this assignment:
there is a nested object of employees each one declare as follows:

```
var employees = {
    employee_1: {
        name: NAME,
        workingHoursPerDay: NUMBER,
        paymentPerHour: calculatePaymentPerHour(workingHoursPerDay),
        salary: calculateSalary(workingHoursPerDay, paymentPerHour),
    },
}
```

so I was trying to do this by send a value of `workingHoursPerDay` to function declare as :

```
function calculatePaymentPerHour(workingHours)
{
    if (workingHours > 8)
        return 150
    else if (workingHours < 8)
    {
        if (workingHours >= 4)
            return 80
        else
            return 30
    }
    else
        return 100
}
```

and it will return value to store it in `paymentPerHour` property 
but there an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: workingHoursPerDay is not defined

so I try to send `workingHoursPerDay` property  by adding this after passing it to function
as `calculatePaymentPerHour(this.workingHoursPerDay),`
but I found the value of `workingHoursPerDay` sending to the function as Undefined.

so how can I send the actual value to the function?

Comment: you can replace `workingHoursPerDay` with `NUMBER` since it has the same value

Comment: you should define that variable (this.workingHoursPerDay) before that employee object

Comment: Can you please show the part of your code where you call `calculatePaymentPerHour(this.workingHoursPerDay)` ? It's possile the problem is that you do not have a `this` in that context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access properties of an object while you initialize that object.

Here are a couple alternative ways of doing this (that will work).

```js
// Method 1 - Create object
var employees = {
    employee_1: {
        name: NAME,
        workingHoursPerDay: NUMBER,
        paymentPerHour: ,
        salary: calculateSalary(workingHoursPerDay, paymentPerHour),
    },
}
employees.employee_1.paymentPerHour = calculatePaymentPerHour(employees.employee_1)
employees.employee_1.salary = calculateSalary(employees.employee_1.workingHoursPerDay, employees.employee_1.paymentPerHour)

// Method 2 - Calculate first, then create Object
const paymentPerHour = calculatePaymentPerHour(NUMBER)
const salary = calculateSalary(NUMBER, paymentPerHour)
const employees = {
  employee_1: {
    name: NAME,
    workingHoursPerDay: NUMBER,
    paymentPerHour, // Shorter way of writing 'paymentPerHour: paymentPerHour,'
    salary, // See above
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related with the context of the `this` keyword. Your function `calculatePaymentPerHour` is declared in `global` context so when yo call it with `this.workingHoursPerDay` the `this` keyword refers to the global object `window`.

You can use the `bind` method to set explicitly the value of `this`.

```
var employees = {
    employee_1: {
        name: NAME,
        workingHoursPerDay: NUMBER,
        paymentPerHour: calculatePaymentPerHour,
        salary: calculateSalary,
    },
}

employees.employee_1.paymentPerHour.bind(employees.employee_1, employees.employee_1.workingHoursPerDay)
```

The `bind` functions creates a copy of the `calculatePaymentPerHour` setting the provided `this` context and the params you want to pass to the function.

Same with `calculateSalary`.

You can check more about `this` context [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)